# Preg_match(_all) can't collect some data from Google

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm creating a tool for my websites to see what position they are in Google on different keywords.

Now, I want to collect this part of their sourcecode:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/" class=l onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','','1','','0CBoQFjAA')">Linktitle in Google!</a>
```

The problem is that the preg_match OR preg_match_all function doesn't match "onmousedown" or "this.href" or the ,'1' part of the link. And that is exactly the part i need...

Does anyone has an idea why this is, and more important.. how to solve this???

The code I use is obvious.. i even tried to use "/onmousedown/" or "/\'1\'/" but it didn't help.

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: If you want to extract some data from an HTML string : **do not use regular expressions !** Use a DOM parser -- see http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: First of all, since you're new to SO: You title should be a question, not a statement. This is not a bulletin board.
Then: please add a text snippet of what your source is, and mark the parts that you want to select via preg_match.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the ethical and possible legal implications of scraping Google, you should not be using regular expressions to extract portions of HTML. Regular expressions were not designed to parse HTML and are not equipped for the specific grammar.

Try using a HTML parser, such as [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). It was designed to parse HTML/XML.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'm new in PHP and really need a tool for this, i'll check the DOMDocument..

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, you are not allowed to **scrape** their website.

Their robot.txt is here: http://www.google.com/robots.txt.

That said, it's a bit hypocritical coming from a company whose whole business model is to scrape other people's websites.

Consider yourself warned.

The regex is simple:

```
<a [^<]*class=l.*?</a>
```

Now, for the folks who claim that HTML can not be parsed with regex... yes, you are right, you can not **parse** html in regex. But let's not be ridiculous here.

Extracting a specific block of text from an HTML page with a known format is definitely possible (and easy) to do in regex. That's what regex is for.

This is not "parsing HTML", and in a case such as this one, where the format is known and the application non-critical, regex does just fine.

---

I just checked and there is an API from Google which allows you to make up to 100 queries for free on a custom search engine.
http://www.google.com/cse/
https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=customsearch&pli=1#welcome

It requires a Google account and an API key, which you can get at the links above.

Warning, wadding through the legalese is going to be considerably harder than writing your **scraper**

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to parse the anchor tag of google search result

```
function parseAnchor($strAnchor)
{
//$strAnchor = "<a onmousedown=\"return clk(this.href,'','','','2','','0CBwQFjAB')\" class=\"l\" href=\"http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php\"><em>PHP</em>: strpos - Manual</a>";

$str_parts = explode(" ",$strAnchor);
$start_index = stripos($str_parts[4],"\"");
$length = strrpos($str_parts[4],"\"") - $start_index;
$link = substr($str_parts[4],$start_index+1,$length-1); //will print the link
print $link;

//Now get postion
$onmousedown_parts = explode(",",$str_parts[2]);

$position = trim($onmousedown_parts[4],"\'");
print "<br>$position"; //will print position
}
```

Try this to parse HTML page

```
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He is trying to get the anchor from the page, he is NOT trying to parse the anchor. To check for his position, all he needs is an array containing all the anchors, and a simple array search to find out one, if any, contains his url.

Comment: @Sylerdrag, He ultimately wants to get the Position and link from the anchor tag, this function will work perfectly... He just need to call this fuction against each anchor tag.

Comment: Even with DomDocument the "onmousedown" part is missing in the source i picked up...

Comment: @Freddy, take the anchor part from html and pass this to `parseAnchor` function. it will do the required parsing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **PHP Class: Google Keyword Position** for that

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5554-PHP-Determine-the-position-of-a-keyword-in-Google.html

**EX:**

File: **google_position.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Google Keyword Position</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body >
  <form name="url_kw" action="search.php" method="get">
      <label for="url">URL:</label>
      <input type="text" name="url" id="url" size="55" value="<?= isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'http://' ?>" />
      <br />
      <label for="keyword">Keyword:</label>
      <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" size="35" value="<?= isset($_GET['keyword']) ? $_GET['keyword'] : null ?>" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="SEARCH" onclick="this.value='Searching...';" />
      <input type="button" value="CANCEL" onclick="javascript: window.location='<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>';" />
      <br />
  </form>
</body>
```

file **search.php**

```
<?
include('KeywordPosition.php');
$position=new KeywordPosition($_GET['url'],$_GET['keyword'],10); // you can change the 10 to 100 to get more results :)
$index=$position->GetPosition();
if($index==-1)
echo 'Not in search results';
else
echo 'You are at '.$index;
?>
```

Live example @ http://x.co/Z493